# Eloquent query on columns of parent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am able to search in some columns of my model Unit.

```
$units = Unit::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')        
            ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(15);
```

Unit belongs to a model named Property:

```
public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
    }
```

How could I search in the attributes of the property?

I tried:

```
$units = Unit::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')        
            ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(15);
            ->orWhere('property.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(15);
```

but I get following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'property.name' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : 
I assume that your tables are : `units` and `properties` and their primary keys are both `id` and foreign key in units is : `property_id`

```
$units = Unit::select('units.*')
        ->where('units.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')        
        ->orWhere('units.address', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->join('properties','properties.id','=','units.property_id')
        ->orWhere('properties.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: this seems to work, thanks! but I only want the unit columns in the $units variable (otherwise I have too many duplicate column names) Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I edited it, please check it 
Don't forget to make my answer helpful :))